# Delete Options from two dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, listbox

So I have two dropdowns,like this:

```
<select id="listbox" name="listbox" multiple="multiple">
            <option> value a </option>
            <option> value b </option>
            <option> value c </option>
 </select>


<select id="listbox2" name="listbox2" multiple="multiple">
            <option> value 1 </option>
            <option> value 2 </option>
            <option> value 3 </option>
 </select>
```

So when the user selects `value a` and click on "delete" button,it should delete `value a` and its corresponding position `value 1` and vice-versa.

I have a Javascript code but it doesn't work properly,here it is:

```
function removeOption() {
    var x = new Array();
    x[0] = document.getElementById("listbox");
    x[1] = document.getElementById("listbox2");

    x[0].remove(x[0].selectedIndex);
    x[1].remove(x[1].selectedIndex);
}
```

Could you guys help me out????

Comment: are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: yes I am,it would be actually easier if it was in Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function

```
function removeselected(d1,d2){
             element=document.getElementById(d1);
             element1=document.getElementById(d2);
             var value= new Array();
             var value1= new Array();
             while(element.selectedIndex != -1)
             {
                var t=element.selectedIndex;
                value.push(element.options[t]);
                value1.push(element1.options[t]);
                element.options[t].selected = false;
             }
             for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
             {
                 element.removeChild(value[i]);
                 element1.removeChild(value1[i]);
             };

   }
```

for call use this

```
  function remover(){
     removeselected('listbox','listbox2');
     removeselected('listbox2','listbox');
  }
```

when call remove all selected from dropdowns and similar index from other dropdowns

Comment: Your function works too,but it has the same problem as the above does

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function removeOption() {
    var listbox = document.getElementById('listbox');
    var listbox2 = document.getElementById('listbox2');

    var selectedIndex = 
        (listbox.selectedIndex == -1) ? listbox2.selectedIndex : listbox.selectedIndex;

    var selItem1 = listbox.options[selectedIndex];
    var selItem2 = listbox2.options[selectedIndex];

    selItem1.remove();
    selItem2.remove();
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mDX9Q/

Comment: your function works,however,it only delete both options if it is selected at the first dropdown,if you choose a option from the second dropdown,it will not work